# I want to get the content of one phtml file

Tags: magento2

I want to get the **content** of one `phtml` file,and then  regard it  as data that be pushed one array.

Anyone who knows what should I do ? 
the `phtml` file  :

```
 <div class="product-integrate-list">
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
  <div class="product-integrate-item transition row <?php if ($product['selected']) echo 'selected'; ?>" style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; cursor: pointer;" category-id="<?php echo $product['categoryId']; ?>" product-id="<?php echo $product['productId']?>">
    <div class="image col-sm-3" style="padding: 1.4em;">
      <img src="image/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" style="height: 50px;" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding: 1em;">
      <h4><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h4>
      <p><?php echo $product['price']; ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I want get it and push in one array `$result['data']` which is made up of the content of phtml file

Comment: From where? Write more and what you have tried.

Comment: Please explain briefly

Comment: I  had already updated my question,please give me some advice,thanks